# Правильный способ отцентрировать <div> элемент во Vue.js приложении

Tags: css, vue.js

Vue.js приложение, корневой компонент App.

Задача:

**1. (Основной вопрос)** Отображение на десктопе: Компонент full-screen занимает 100% ширины и высоты окна браузера. Компонент centered отцентрирован внутри него (и горизонтально, и вертикально).

**2. (Дополнительно)** Отображение на мобильном устройстве: Компонент centered также растягивается на 100% по ширине и высоте.

У меня оба условия выполняются. Но не уверен, сделал ли я это правильно. Вопрос: может быть есть более правильный/простой способ добиться заданных условий?

Код:

```
<template id="app">
    <div id="full-screen">
        <div id="centered"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    #app {
        font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    #full-screen {
        background: black;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #centered {
        margin: auto;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: white;
        width: 480px;
        height: 800px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
        #full-screen {
            background: initial;
            position: initial;
            height: initial;
            width: initial;
        }

        #centered {
            margin: initial;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: initial; left: initial; bottom: initial; right: initial;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы выравниваете элементы при помощи абсолютного позиционирования, а это уже не правильно в любом случае.

Используйте flex-box. задайте блоку `#full-screen` следующие стили

```
#full-screen{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

хорошая статья по флексам https://html5.by/blog/flexbox/